# table() function doesn't add number of males and females together in R (total beginner)

Tags: r

I want to create a frequency table that displays the following:

1. Total number of students
2. Male students
3. Female students

I tried the following:

```
read.cvs2("Questionnaire")
data <- Questionnaire
students <- table(data$GENDER)
mStudents <- table(data$GENDER[data$GENDER == 1])
fStudents <- table(data$GENDER[data$GENDER == 2])
```

When I create the frequency table (as shown below) it the numbers are correct for male and female students but not for the total number of students.

```
freqTab <- cbind(students, mStudents, fStudents)
```

WHERE I BELIEVE THE ERROR IS:

in the environment pane under values, "students" this info: 'table' int [1:2 (1d)] and then the number of male and female students. How can I make this one number?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you? (Example with the built-in `mtcars` data set.)

```r
c(total = nrow(mtcars), table(mtcars$cyl))
## total     4     6     8 
##    32    11     7    14
```

or

```r
addmargins(table(mtcars$cyl))
##   4   6   8 Sum 
##  11   7  14  32
```